# Rotate 2D points using openCV and python

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, rotation

I am using `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D` to get a 2x3 matrix to rotate a source image. This works fine. Now i have several 2D coordinates, which represent points in the unrotated image. 
Can I use the same matrix to rotate the indiviual points and if yes, how?
If i understood correcty, I should be able to multiply the matrix with the (x,y)-coordinates, but no matter which combination of matrix and points I try, I never get simple x and y coordinates as a result.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

the rotation matrix is

```
[[  9.24630834e-01   3.80864571e-01   1.52747702e-01]
 [ -3.80864571e-01   9.24630834e-01   1.57068951e+02]]
```

What I am doing so far:

```
point = np.array([marker.x, marker.y, 1])
transform = rot_matrix * point.T
print transform
```

But this does not give me a 2x1 matrix as it should, but:

```
[[  2.10815830e+02   7.92198307e+01   1.52747702e-01]
 [ -8.68371221e+01   1.92323213e+02   1.57068951e+02]]
```

Comment: can you include a few line example of the definition of the piece of code that works, just so I'm clear how to fix it? I've an idea how to do it but I need to see what you have working to comment.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, FlashTek's answer gave me the correct hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this [site](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html). As `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D` creates a affine transformation, you can write the result of the call like this:

[image].

If you now want to transform a 2D point you have to calculate this expression

[image]
[image]

This should solve your issue.
(All images come from the referenced documentation page)

Edit: Regarding your edit: You cannot use the `*` operator, but should maybe use `np.dot()`. The `*` operator is only performing a real matrix-vector product for matrix object. Otherwise, it is performing a element-wise product.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

Define two arrays xArray and yArray with the points you want to transform

```
for indexItem in xrange(len(xArray)):
  point = np.array([xArray[indexItem], yArray[indexItem], 1])
  transform = rot_matrix * point.T
  print transform
```

Its not quite as eloquent but should do the trick. If you really want to create an array of markers then you must use:

```
 markers = zip( xArray, yArray)
```